# 「まだ要る」いけません？なぜですか？

Tags: adverbs, collocations

> 俺の本まだ要るの？返せよ！

こういう感じで言いたいですけど。なんていうか、違和感？なんとなく、変な感じの気がします。「～がまだいる」は聞いたことない気がします。それ、言わないじゃないですか。

> その本はまだ必要です

というのはもっとナチュラルそうですけど。これは何故ですか。「まだいる」は正しいですか？じゃないと、"Do you still need that?"を日本語にどう直せばいいですか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> これ、まだ要る？
> -- うん、まだ要る。
> -- ううん、もう要らない。

のように、カジュアルな日常会話で使ってると思います。変な感じはしません。

> その本はまだ必要ですか。
> -- はい、まだ必要です。
> -- いいえ、もう必要ではありません。

のように言うと、かなりフォーマルで硬い感じになります。「いる」より「必要」のほうがより硬い感じがします。

> その本はまだ要りますか。
> -- はい、まだ要ります。
> -- いいえ、もう要りません。

のように言ってもいいです。

> 俺の本まだ要るの？返せよ！

と言ってもおかしくありません。

> 俺の本まだ必要なの？返せよ！

でもいいと思うのですが、「俺」「なの？」「返せよ！」などカジュアルな言葉と一緒に使うなら、「いる」のほうがよりしっくりするかもしれません。

Comment: 丁寧に教えて頂きありがとうございました。質問する前に「まだ要る」ググってみてたんですけど、検索結果的にはあんまり多くなかったみたいです。「まだ必要」の方がいっぱい多いみたいですが。"Reverso Context"で同じように「まだ要る」は一つしかなかったんです。[今ググると、首位と二位](https://www.google.co.jp/search?source=hp&ei=fPz4X6ivNoaQ5wK9w77wAg&q=%22%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A0%E8%A6%81%E3%82%8B%22&oq=%22%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A0%E8%A6%81%E3%82%8B%22)のはこの投稿みたいですが…

Comment: 「要る」は平仮名で書くことのほうが多いからですかね。。